# How to implement pagedlist in mvc when using view models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

I am using viewmodel concept in mvc 4. I am posting data to db and as soon as post displaying in grid below also.  So I have used view model concept. This is my viemodel class

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public document upload_document { get; set; }
        public IList<document> Upload_List { get; set; }

    }
```

I have many fields in document so I am not posting fields. I have gone through some articles and they are returning something like this: `return View(students.ToList());where student is var`. But I am returning model in all action methods. Also in view they have written

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

but I have this in my view

```
@model c3card.Dal.EDModel.MyViewModel
```

So, how can return model that contains pagenum,page size? How can I use this pagedlist concept when using view models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to map your entities to view models and still be able to page through them, then you need to use `StaticPagedList`. In order for the standard method of using `PagedList` to work, it needs to be passed a queryable (unevaluated), so that it can limit the query to only pull the proper number of records. If you're mapping to a view model, though, then that's going to evaluate the query.

What you need is something like:

```
public ActionResult Students(int? page)
{
    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    var pageSize = 10;

    var totalStudents = db.Students.Count();
    var students = db.Students.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    var model = // map `students` to your view model

    var pagedList = new StaticPagedList<MyViewModel>(model, pageNumber, pageSize, totalStudents);

    return View(pagedList);
}
```

Then, the model for your view is:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Namespace.To.MyViewModel>
```

Comment: var pagedList = new StaticPagedList<MyViewModel>(model, pageNumber, pageSize, totalStudents); In this line i am getting System.ArgumentOutofrange exception.

Comment: Well, the last three params are all `int`. So, the only way you're going to get `ArgumentOutOfRange` is if you're passing a value greater than `Int32.MaxValue` or less than `Int32.MinValue`.

Comment: How can i overcome from this?

Comment: You can't. It only takes ints. However, if you truly have more than the max 32-bit integer records, no one will ever page that far. We're talking billions here.